# Are there any input assist tools in TexShop like the one in WinEdt?

Tags: texshop, winedt

By  "input assist tools", I mean the graphical interface in WinEdt with tabs like 'symbols','Greeks','maths'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know WinEdt, but TeXShop has both a LaTeX panel (with many subparts) which gives you access to many commonly used LaTeX elemnts,  and a Matrix panel which provides a simple way to enter small tables and matrices. These are both found under the Window menu item.

**LaTeX Panel**

[image: LaTeX panel]

**Matrix panel**

[image: Matrix Panel]

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanna. Since I am very new to both Mac OS and TexShop, I didin't find it. Thanks a lot for your warmly answer.